# How to use cors-anywhere with my express app?

Tags: node.js, express, cors-anywhere

I am trying to make cors-anywhere to work in my nodejs/express without success.

First I use `express-cors-anywhere` like this :

```
const anywhere = require('express-cors-anywhere')
app.use("/cors-anywhere", anywhere())
```

but get the following error :

```
anywhere is not a function
```

I've tried to use the native `cors-anywhere` library but I don't know how to implement this on an express js app :

```
var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
    requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
    removeHeaders: ['cookie', 'cookie2']
}).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Running CORS Anywhere on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

How to integrate with existing expressjs server [#81](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/81)

```
let proxy = corsAnywhere.createServer({
  originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
  requireHeaders: [], // Do not require any headers.
  removeHeaders: [] // Do not remove any headers.
});

/* Attach our cors proxy to the existing API on the /proxy endpoint. */
api.get('/proxy/:proxyUrl*', (req, res) => {
  req.url = req.url.replace('/proxy/', '/'); // Strip '/proxy' from the front of the URL, else the proxy won't work.
  proxy.emit('request', req, res);
});
```